How to accept an annotation as an argument inside another annotation?
I want to create a validation annotation which will validate one or more fields if another field is not empty i.e dependent validations.
I am designing it like below:
@DependentValidation (
    dependentField = "vehicleType",
    targetField = ["wheels","doors"]
    validationType = @Min(4)
)

So, we could put a rule which says "If vehicleType field is not empty, then wheels should be 4 and doors should be 4"
Now can the field validationType accept Jakarta validation annotation as argument? So that inside my ConstraintValidator implementation, I can get parameter defined (4) inside the passed annotation of @Min?
I tried declaring validationType like
Class<? extends Annotation> validationType(); But that doesn't work.
Please help

I can figure out something like:
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface DependentValidation {
    String dependentField();
    String[] targetField();
    Min min() default @Min(0);
    Max max() default @Max(1000);
    ...
}


@DependentValidation(dependentField = "vehicleType", targetField = {"wheels", "doors"}, min = @Min(4) )
public class MyBean {
  ...



No I cannot do this, as it is not just min and max that I want to use. I would like to use all jakarta validation annotations here.
